# Does redis-py automatically use evalsha for registered scripts?

Tags: redis, redis-py

When I register a Lua script to a redis client:

```
script = redis_client.register_script(lua_string)
```

and then run the script with the default client:

```
script(keys, args)
```

does this automatically use evalsha internally or does it send the whole script to the server every time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Here's the (abridged) [source code](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/5109cb4f6b610e8d5949716a16435afbbf35075a/redis/client.py#L2921):

```py
class Script(object):
    def __call__(self, keys=[], args=[], client=None):
        if isinstance(client, BasePipeline):
            # Make sure the pipeline can register the script before executing.
            client.scripts.add(self)

        return client.evalsha(self.sha, len(keys), *args)
```